# Tak.Run ContinueWith is not working updating the UI on android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, asynchronous, task

Hi I have this xamarin with cocossharp project and I tried using `Task.Run` but the UI update is only working on iOS.

Here is my code.

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await UserService.InitLoadOtherPlayerResoucres();
}).ContinueWith(a =>
{
    PlayerTwoFinal = UserService.OtherPlayersProfile;
    PlayerTwoFinal.ContentSize = new CCSize(PlayerTwo.ContentSize.Width,
        PlayerTwo.ContentSize.Height);
    PlayerTwoFinal.Position = new CCPoint(PlayerTwo.PositionX, PlayerTwo.PositionY);
    Player2.AddChild(PlayerTwoFinal, 0);
    Debug.WriteLine(">>>>> LOAD ORIGINAL IMAGE COMPLETE");
});
```

I tried `Task.Factory.StartNew` but no luck.

This is the code for `UserService.InitLoadOtherPlayerResoucres()`:

[image: First Part]
[image: Second Part]

Answer (score 2):

`ContinueWith()` won't necessarily be executing the code on the UI thread.

There is an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith__1_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0__System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_) that you can use to force `ContinueWith()` to use the UI thread, but really you should be going fully async:

```
var a = await UserService.InitLoadOtherPlayerResoucres();

PlayerTwoFinal = UserService.OtherPlayersProfile;
PlayerTwoFinal.ContentSize = new CCSize(PlayerTwo.ContentSize.Width, PlayerTwo.ContentSize.Height);
PlayerTwoFinal.Position = new CCPoint(PlayerTwo.PositionX, PlayerTwo.PositionY);
Player2.AddChild(PlayerTwoFinal, 0);
Debug.WriteLine(">>>>> LOAD ORIGINAL IMAGE COMPLETE");
```

By using `await` you are ensuring that the UI thread will be kept available whilst `UserService.InitLoadOtherPlayerResoucres()` executes.

Using `Task.Run` is also superfluous and will only be introducing overhead.

---

**Update as per amended question**

Although `InitLoadOtherPlayerResoucres` has been decorated with the `async` keyword, it actually isn't asynchronous at all and thus will block, irrespective of whether it is awaited.

Ideally you should re-write `InitLoadOtherPlayerResoucres` to be truly asynchronous, which would ensure that the UI thread will be released when the asynchronous work is being done.

When you call `GetByteArrayAsync().Result`; `.Result` will block the thread until the `Task` generated by `GetByteArrayAsync()` has completed. Instead this should be:

```
var streamImage = await webClient.GetByteArrayAsync(OtherPlayersUserPhoto);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jonathan, what I wanted to do is wait UserService.InitLoadOtherPlayerResoucres(); to be excuted or done first before running the other code because the resources will given by running UserService.InitLoadOtherPlayerResoucres();

But without affecting the UI

Comment: @JanGenvherPapica That's exactly what will happen. When you hit the `await`, the current thread will be released, and the remainder of your method will be scheduled to resume once `UserService.InitLoadOtherPlayerResoucres()` has been completed. The Xamarin `SynchronizationContext` will ensure the method is resumed on the UI thread.

Comment: I used that code @Johnathan but still the app freeze 3-5 seconds before the ui works again. This mean it still wait for the await UserService.InitLoadOtherPlayerResoucres(); to be finished

Comment: @JanGenvherPapica Can you post your `UserService.InitLoadOtherPlayerResoucres` method? That might be doing the blocking.

Comment: @JanGenvherPapica See update. Your `InitLoadOtherPlayerResoucres` isn't currently `async` and will block.